# Using multiple embedded datastores with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to set up a Spring Boot application using Spring Data JPA, Neo4J and MongoDB. The goal is to be able to save different entities in each datastore, as well as using cross-store entities.

The project seems to work well with each store individually, but saving a JPA entity raises this exception :

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'persist' call; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'persist' call
```

This exception is not raised if I remove all neo4J and mongoDB related code.

Here is a link to the project on github :

[GitHub](https://github.com/raphael-jungers/CrossStoreSpringBoot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it working by using the configuration of [this](https://github.com/mangrish/spring-data-jpa-neo4j-with-boot) project.

It looks like I had to add an "transactionManagerRef" attribute to the @EnableJpaRepositories annotation, a bit more configuration for Transition Managers, and modify some dependencies.